# How to override AcDbEntity::transformBy to get custom entity transformation while moving or scaling?

Tags: c++, objectarx

I'm implementing a custom entity derived from AcDbEntity. I draw some lines and text label in overloaded subWorldDraw function and I want my entity to be able to be scaled, moved, rotated, so as I understand I should override AcDbEntity::transformBy, as was written [here](http://arxdummies.blogspot.com/2005/06/class-14-creating-custom-entity-step.html). But when I try to add this method, compiler rises an error, which tells, that this method is sealed. Is any another way to make my entity responsible to transformation done by user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer [here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/objectarx/page/2/) - in new ObjectArx versions not AcDbEntity::transformBy, but AcDbEntity::subTransformBy method can be overridden. It's also touch on other virtual methods, like AcDbEntity::worldDraw -> AcDbEntity::subWorldDraw.